# Spring Boot Swagger authentication with apikey

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to set an api key for swagger to secure my APIs.

Below is code I have:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import springfox.documentation.builders.*;
import springfox.documentation.service.*;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${version.number}")
    private String version;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {

        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("My API")
                .description("My API Documentation")
                .version(version)
                .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("APIKey", authorizationScopes));
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("APIKey", "APIKey", "header");
    }
}
```

The image below shows the UI. I can hit any API with any API key or even when I didn't enter anything, I can still access the APIs. I would like to set a key in the code, maybe in a properties file then configure it in swagger so that every time when anyone tries to access the APIs, they provide the apikey I specified.

[image]

Comment: I'm also interested about this. Have you maybe found the solution?

Comment: you need to bring spring security in picture, along with that you need to implement filter that will validate APIKey available in request header. you need to bypass swagger related URIs in filter using shouldNotFilter method.